# 1 Solution with Xamarin Classic and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

What's the best approach to add a Xamarin.Forms project to a solution that already has a Xamarin.Android, a Xamarin.iOS and a Core project?

I want to avoid maintaining two Core projects, have a bloated PCL and any MvvmCross ViewPresenter issues.

I can think of linking the files from the existing Core Project into the Xamarin.Forms Core project. But will I run into problems that I cannot foresee right now? Are there better solutions out there? What are you using?
Thanks!

Comment: The current PCL based Xamarin.Forms itself is not easy to use, as PCL rips out so many APIs. You'd better wait till .NET Standard support is completed by Microsoft/Xamarin (they are working on that), then Xamarin.Forms will be much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through that exact scenario before and here's what happened:

- I had a separate Xamarin Forms PCL project in my solution. The project had a single Android Activity that rendered all the Xamarin Forms.
- I moved that Android activity to the classic Xamarin Android project.
- I made the classic Xamarin Android project reference both my core PCL and the Xamarin Forms PCL projects.
- Now my classic Xamarin project had all the native Android Activities in addition to a single Android Activity that renders all the Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Where do you keep the viewmodels and services if you have two PCLs?

Comment: I can keep them in any of them (The core or the Xamarin Forms) because now, the native Android project references both. In my case I added them to the core as it already had some view models defined, and made the Xamarin Forms project reference the core project.

Comment: OK, so if I understand this right your Xamarin.Android project references a PCL that also includes the Xamarin.Forms views, right? I kinda wanted to avoid that

Comment: Yes, because in the end Xamarin Forms render in an Android Activity which must be included in your Android project.

Comment: Your view models should be totally decoupled from your views. At least that´s the aim of using view-models. So you can put them in a separate PCL project that can be referenced by either Android and the xamarin.forms projects